# Using column values as filenames to save spark dataframe

Tags: pyspark

How to save a spark dataframe to file using the column values as  filenames . is it possible?

```
+--------------------------+----------+-----------------+-----------------------------------+
|ID                        |CITY      |DATE             |name                               |
+--------------------------+----------+-----------------+-----------------------------------+
|1                         |          |2011-01-01       |20110101_DATA.snappy.parquet       |
|2                         |          |2011-01-01       |20110101_DATA.snappy.parquet       |
|3                         |          |2011-01-01       |20110101_DATA.snappy.parquet       |
|4                         |Chicago   |2011-01-01       |20110101_DATA.snappy.parquet       |
|5                         |Mansfield |2011-01-02       |20110102_DATA.snappy.parquet       |
|6                         |Pittsburgh|2011-01-02       |20110102_DATA.snappy.parquet       |
|7                         |          |2011-01-02       |20110102_DATA.snappy.parquet       |
|8                         |Clarion   |2011-01-03       |20110103_DATA.snappy.parquet       |
|9                         |Storrs    |2011-01-03       |20110103_DATA.snappy.parquet       |
|10                        |          |2011-01-03       |20110103_DATA.snappy.parquet       |
+--------------------------+----------+-----------------+-----------------------------------+
```

Expected Output:

Partition By Date and use the name value as the filename when saving the data as parquet. The o/p would be 3 files

```
/DATE=2011-01-01/20110101_DATA.snappy.parquet
/DATE=2011-01-02/20110102_DATA.snappy.parquet
/DATE=2011-01-03/20110103_DATA.snappy.parquet
```

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: @ggeop Updated with example

Comment: One more definition, you need only empty files or you want to have data inside? If yes which data. The data frame will be large?

Comment: Yes the files will be having data. it will have all columns except the name columns and DATE(since DATE will be present in partition)

Answer (score 1):

Spark cannot natively create custom names in your output parquet file as you want. You can use the following code, but it's not a scalable solution because you use `.collect()` action.

```
# In large dataframe maybe it will not work
unique_filename = [row.name for row in df.select('name').distinct().collect()]

for filename in  unique_filenames:
  output_filename = "/DATE=" + filename[0:4] + "-" + filename[4:6] + "-" + filename[6:8] + "/" + filename
  df.select("ID", "CITY", "DATE") 
    .filter(df['name']==filename) \
    .write \
    .parquet(output_filename)
```

You will have exacly what you want:

```
/DATE=2011-01-01/20110101_DATA.snappy.parquet
/DATE=2011-01-02/20110102_DATA.snappy.parquet
/DATE=2011-01-03/20110103_DATA.snappy.parquet
```

Comment: If I got thousands of filename, Can you implement multiprocessing here for acceleration ? Thanks